# Kotlin n must be positive crash

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting this error where stack trace says:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive.
And it shows the bug on this lines. In the tutorials that i'm learning to make this app they fixed this problem with: if (pieces.size >= 2). But
obviously it's not working somehow.

```
 private fun readDictionaryfile(){
        val reader = Scanner(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.recidva))
        while (reader.hasNextLine()){
            val line = reader.nextLine()
            Log.d("Mihajlo","the line is:$line")
            val pieces = line.split("\t")
            if (pieces.size >= 2){
            words.add(pieces[0])
            wordToDefn.put(pieces[0],pieces[1])
            }
        }
    }
private fun setupList() {
        val rand = Random()
        val index = rand.nextInt(words.size)
        val randomWor = words[index]
        randomWord.text = randomWor

        defn.clear()
        defn.add(wordToDefn[randomWor]!!)
        words.shuffle()
        for (otherWord in words.subList(0,4)){
            if (otherWord == randomWor || defn.size > 5){
                continue
            }
            defn.add(wordToDefn[otherWord]!!)
        }
        defn.shuffle()
```

Comment: *it shows the bug on this lines* which line exactly?

Comment: val index = rand.nextInt(words.size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to generate a random number from 0, which is less than 0. Give it a positive number so it can give you a sensible result. Check words.size it should be bigger than 0

Comment: @MihajloMilosevic your word.size is returning 0 because your words list empty. You can add first data to your word list then you can try to generate random

Comment: @MihajloMilosevic if this worked for you please checked as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your words.size gives 0, as words are empty. Then you try to random using this value -> 0. U cant do this, you have to random 1 or higher. Thats why you get this error.

Just check if the words are not empty and then try to random.